# Is it possible to do continuous deployment CI/CD of an Azure Function through a Linux Environment via Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-pipelines, azure-linux

When creating a function in Azure through a Linux environment it seems CI/CD is completely missing from it's capabilities as I can't see any actual files. My VS code tells me this

`Error: This plan does not support viewing files.`

and when I try to deploy my files to the server through the Azure pipeline everything works except for the 
`Azure App Service Deploy`

Which tells me this.

```
2020-04-21T19:48:37.6676043Z ##[error]Failed to deploy web package to App Service.
2020-04-21T19:48:37.6689536Z ##[error]Error: Error: Failed to deploy web package to App Service. Conflict (CODE: 409)
```

I did get it working directly through VS Code with a windows environment and didn't notice any of those issues.

Can you confirm this is not possible through Linux or perhaps there is a solution for what I am looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- is it possible to do continuous deployment CI/CD of an Azure Function through a Linux Environment via Azure DevOps?

The answer is Yes.

To deploy a Azure Function, you should use [Azure Function App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-function-app?view=azure-devops) task instead of Azure App Service Deploy task. For below example.

```
steps:
- task: AzureFunctionApp@1
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '<Azure service connection>'
    appType: functionAppLinux
    appName: '<Name of function app>'
    #Uncomment the next lines to deploy to a deployment slot
    #Note that deployment slots is not supported for Linux Dynamic SKU
    #deployToSlotOrASE: true
    #resourceGroupName: '<Resource Group Name>'
    #slotName: '<Slot name>'
```

Please check out this document [Continuous delivery by using Azure DevOps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-azure-devops?tabs=csharp) for detailed examples.

Comment: thank you. i will give this a try although in this case I don't think it really matters. Also, not being able to see the directory or files is a drawback for linux I think